# Add day from previous month to Select

Tags: mysql

I have a `SELECT` to give me the booked days of a apartment in a specific month:

```
SELECT db.the_date, db.id_state, db.id_client_booking, bs.class 
    FROM `day_bookings` as db 
    LEFT JOIN `bookings_states` as bs ON bs.id= db.id_state 
    WHERE id_item= 10
    AND YEAR(the_date)= 2016
    AND MONTH(the_date) = 6
```

**How can I add the last day of the previous month to this query?**

I thought about doing a new `LEFT JOIN` with the same query for month 5 but couldn't get it to work, syntax errors all the time.

I tried `UNION ALL` with 2 similar selects and got just the last one.
I also tried nested `SELECT`, but it didn't pass over syntax errors.

Any suggestion on how to add the last month to this result?

Comment: can you give the example ?

Comment: @VipinJain how do you mean? from my failed attemps with nested select and extra left join?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT db.the_date, db.id_state, db.id_client_booking, bs.class 
    FROM `day_bookings` as db 
    LEFT JOIN `bookings_states` as bs ON bs.id= db.id_state 
    WHERE id_item= 10
    AND YEAR(the_date)= 2016
    AND (MONTH(the_date) = 6 OR (MONTH(the_date) = 5 AND DAY(the_date) = 31))
    ;
```

**OR** clause is what you need.

Comment: could also use an in clause

Comment: he just want last day of previous month , so more readable query . `IN` will also do .

Comment: depends how you define readable, also it only makes one call to the function month ( though probably the optimiser will evaluate the same way ). anyway - answers the question

Comment: How will you incorporate the `DATE = 31` condition without `OR` Clause .

Comment: was thinking like `AND (MONTH(the_date) in ( 5, 6 ) AND DAY(the_date) = 31))`

Comment: Interesting, this does this work also if the month before does not have 31 days?

Comment: This will take Only DAY 31 for both Months, Will ignore the rest .You need to Validate your answer , result will come in both .

Comment: Intersting, in cases where month before has 30 or 28 days, is there a solution that serves all cases? I was thinking about `LAST_DAY(MONTH(the_date) = 5)` but that didn't work...

Comment: For that you will need subquery like `select MAX_DATE from month where month = 5` . You might add a sqlfiddle so that queries can be verified .

Comment: your welcome to use that fiddle - im not using it ;)

Comment: @amdixon nice fiddle, thank you also! Do you guys think your solution or mine in the new answer is better/more performant?

Comment: have a look at the explain plans and also use [`benchmark`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark) to compare. may not be much difference

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it using

```
AND the_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2016-06-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY('2016-06-01')
```

this way it works for every month, despite 28, 30 or 31 length months.

So the end query is:

```
SELECT db.the_date, db.id_state, db.id_client_booking, db.id_item, bs.class 
    FROM `day_bookings` as db 
    LEFT JOIN `bookings_states` as bs ON bs.id= db.id_state 
    WHERE id_item= 10
    AND YEAR(the_date)= 2016
    AND the_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2016-06-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY('2016-06-01')
```